# Teaching School Algebra via Programming

Tags: algebra-precalculus, reference-request, education

It seems that there are ideas to teach school algebra (i.e. using variables, working with algebraic expressions and solving equations) via computer programming. 
I need a book or a collection of lesson plans on this subject.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One of the big stumbling blocks for newbie programmers (in imperative languages) is to *un*learn the meaning of "variable." In mathematics, it is a fixed value that you don't know/don't care about; often one of a set of values you want to reason about. In programming, it is a location that holds a value that can be changed by the program.

You might have better luck with functional languages, where a variable is a fixed value; but even then, the same name might hold different values (during a recursion). Besides, functional languages are not precisely popular (I guess because they demand more abstract thinking, recursion seems to be seated somewhere in the more nebulous regions of the average brain).

What I'd think would be more worthwhile is to teach the students how to use a symbolic math package (like [maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net), which is available for free and even runs on Android). Teach them how to set up equations, and leave the routine work to the computer.